# How to unplug from thunderbolt display in a safe way?

Tags: macos, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Whenever to unplug from the thunderbolt display one have to unmount all the devices connected to the display ports. Is there an automated way to do this without having to search for everything in finder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an app in the appstore called undock that does all the unmounting and advice when it's safe to unplug.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/undock/id402359583?mt=12

Answer (score 2):

[Jettison](http://www.stclairsoft.com/Jettison/) from the App Store for $1.99 has helped me with this.

It's a menubar application that helps in 2 ways: You can click and eject all drives (the only problem is that you can't say something like "Only eject drives connected to the Thunderbolt Display"); you can also select an option to eject all drives when putting the computer to sleep (so if you are disconnecting your computer to go somewhere, you can put it to sleep, wait a moment, then unplug everything).

That being said, I now use [Launchbar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) to accomplish this. I just activate Launchbar and select "Eject All Ejectable Volumes". I'm willing to bet other app launchers (Quicksilver, Alfred) can do this just as easily.

Comment: I'll second the LaunchBar recommendation. Having it make it quick to eject all volumes, sleep, lock the screen and other tasks is a big plus for me.

Comment: Jettison sounds like a good option too. Alfred also does the job. I liked undock for being direct to the point. Undock.